# html value set from javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, variables

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var p = s.getMaximum();
</script>

<form action="/cgi-bin/Lib.exe" method="POST" name="checks" ID="Form1">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE="VAR P FROM JAVA SCRIPT HERE?" ID="Text1"><P></form>
```

Possible to pass the javascript value 'p' as the value of input form?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603924/submit-name-value-pair-from-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to read about the Javascript DOM.

Start with the following: 
http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_obj_form.asp

Specifically you're looking to manipulate document.checks.inputbox.value

Edit: Page removed.  Answer can be found here now:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_doc_forms.asp

Answer (score 9):

You can use javascript to set the value of that element to `p`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("Text1").value = p;
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById('Text1').value = p;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("Text1").value = p;
</script>
```

Using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Text1").val(p);
</script>
```